# How can I interpret an infinitive clause?

Tags: infinitive-clauses

I wonder whether an infinitive clause can be interpreted in different ways. For example:

Example 1:

> "It is a joke for me to wear this shirt on streets."
>
> Interpretation no.1: *For me/From my point of view, it is a joke to wear this shirt on streets.*
>
> Interpretation no.2 ("for me" as the subject of the infinitive clause): *The idea/scenario that I wear this shirt on streets is a joke.*

Example 2:

> "It is impossible for me to climb this mountain."
>
> Interpretation no.1: *For me/From my point of view, it is impossible to climb this mountain.*
>
> Interpretation no.2 ("for me" as the subject of the infinitive clause): *The idea/scenario that I climb this mountain is impossible.*

Comment: Your second interpretations are close enough, though note that the subject is just "me". "For" is a subordinator that introduces infinitival clauses that have a subject.

Comment: I think non-of those interpretations describe what the second example conveys. I think the second example basically means you do not see the capacity in yourself to climb the mountain.